# Enumerating all instances of a cloud service in Azure

Tags: azure, cloud, cluster-computing, load-balancing

My cloud service is deployed with two instances by default and has auto-scaling feature on which makes Azure to deploy additional instances as needed. I need to signal *all* instances currently running to invalidate their internal caches. Ideally by POSTing to a public facing url. But Azure load balancer will route the request randomly to one of the instances only.

I probably can utilize Service Bus topics/subscriptions to solve the problem but that looks like overkill. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.changing.aspx:

> #### RoleEnvironment.Changing Event
>
> Occurs before a change to the service configuration is applied to the running instances of a role.
>
> The **Changing** event and the **Changed** event are used together to identify and manage configuration changes to the service model. By using the **Changing** event, an instance can respond to a configuration change [...]

To be honest i can't remember if this is how you do it, but i believe i'm pretty close:

```cs
private void RoleEnvironmentChanging(object sender, RoleEnvironmentChangingEventArgs e) 
{
   if ((e.Changes.Any(change => change is RoleEnvironmentConfigurationSettingChange))) 
   {
      // Deal with e.Cancel
      // Invalidate cache
   }
}
```

Here's more on what events are triggered on configuration change:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/responding-to-role-topology-changes/

> The following diagram shows which events fire in an example scenario containing a single role. 2 instances are deployed initially, the deployment is then scaled to 4 instances, then back down to 3, and finally the deployment is stopped.
>
> [image: events]

Comment: Thanks, I tried this approach. It's unacceptably slow - takes 3-5 minutes on 2 idle `Standard_D2_v2` for my `RoleEnvironmentChanging` callbacks to be triggered.